# Interface 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface' not found

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, symfony-2.8

After upgrading from Symfony 2.3 to 2.8 I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Interface
>   'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface' not found in
>   app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2629

Already tried removing the vendor folder and doing a composer install.

Any ideas?

Comment: And what about `app/console cache:clear` ?

Comment: or just rename the app/bootstrap.php.cache to another name and if it works you can delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the following line to web/app.php and web/app_dev.php:

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
```

And also update app/console.

Found this by comparing my files with a fresh install of Symfony 2.8

Comment: Yep.  bootstrap.php.cache used to include the autoload.php file.  Glad to see it's been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing cached code? It seems like you've procompiled your application into one file `bootstrap.php.cache`. Have you tried removing it.

Otherwise it is always a good idea to do two of the following commands:

`php composer.phar dump-autoload` - update autolod file
`php app/console cache:clear` - removes cache