# Fatal error: Interface 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface' not found in Foundation\Application.php on line 29, on Laravel 7.0

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, composer-php

I haven't been building applications with laravel in a while, and I'm trying to recall by running the code
`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 apitestku`
at the end of the installation there is an error:

> 73 package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use `composer suggest` to see details. Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you
> should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested. Package
> phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No
> replacement was suggested.
>
> Generating optimized autoload files
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>
> Fatal error: Interface
> 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface' not found in C:\laravel\apitestku\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php on line 29

At first I ignored the problem and ran right away `php artisan serve` and i got the error

> Fatal error: Interface
> 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface' not found in C:\laravel\apitestku\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php on line 29

again.

what's causing  `'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface'` not found?
i try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315629/interface-symfony-component-httpkernel-httpkernelinterface-not-found) but not working,
i try solution from [Github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/16713) it's same.

 and how to fix it?

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` is always a good first thing to try.

Comment: Can you run `composer show` and check if `symfony/http-kernel` is in the list or run the command with the package name as argument? That way we can be sure it was installed as expected. If it's not in there you can run `composer why-not symfony/http-kernel` to check why it was not installed

Comment: Using PHP 7.4 I ran the composer command in your question and got a clean install of Laravel Framework 7.30.1.  Might want to just try again?  Sometimes hiccups occur.  Maybe clear composer's cache and update composer if needed.  Or maybe it's your PHP version?  Really just guessing on possible solutions.  It all seemed to have worked for me.

Comment: yes, thankyou for all. i try this ```composer clearcache``` -> ```composer install --optimize-autoloader``` -> ```php artisan key:generate``` -> ```php artisan serve``` and it's work for me.